# Is this story true? How can a Rishi curse a God?

Tags: vishnu, rishi, curse

https://vedicfeed.com/shukracharya-the-guru-of-asuras/

Rishi Bhrigu, the father of Shukracharya and the husband of Kavyamata, curses Vishnu saying,“ Hey Vishnu! By killing a woman, you have breached Dharma and I, hereby, curse you to take seven births as a Human”. (However, later, Rishi Bhrigu breathes life into his wife Kavyamata.)

So it is written in this article.

I know that aavatars are not humans.

So who are supposed to be those humans?

Can Rishis curse Gods?

Comment: 'gods' is a loose translation of the word 'devas' which properly translated is 'bright ones'. The office of a god is a temporary one, not permanent. Devas are reborn as men when their karma as a 'god' is over. The English term with a capital 'G' is usually referenced to Ishta.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda you mean that Visnu and Shiva are men???? Explain more detail way please ji. Also please provide the Shastras of this.

Comment: Rishis are very highly spiritually advanced and and purified so they can curse Gods as well. But since u referred vishnu I would like to tell he's free from all activities performed by anyone and does not affect him in any way. He just accepted the curse to keep the word of such a great Rishi.